# Macro adding multiple unneeded series to XY Scatter Chart

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm writing a macro to create an XY Scatter chart in Excel 2010 but having some trouble. I am trying to assign .Name, .XValues, and .Value using a loop but whenever my macro completes there are several unneeded entries in the chart. Here is my code:

```
    For m = 4 To 36
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Name = Range("A" & m)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).XValues = Range("Q" & m)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Values = Range("R" & m)
    Next m
```

For some reason the first three series being added are M1:M2, N1:N2, and O1:O2 but I have no idea why. I only want data from columns A, Q, and R. Also at the bottom of the chart there are always ten addition series (e.g. Series1 through Series10). Does anyone know why this happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You must have some other code that is adding the first three series, `M1:M2`, `N1:N2`, and `O1:O2`, otherwise, this line (`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(m).Name = Range("A" & m)` ) will fail because `m=4` while `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count` would = `0`.

Comment: There isn't much to my macro.  I am certain the other values are not defined anywhere.  The suggestion Tim provided about deleting any series right after the chart is created fixed my problem.

Comment: Tim's suggestion to delete the series works because there are 3 series already in the chart (otherwise your code would fail trying to assign `Name` to series 4 which can only be done if there are 4 series in the chart).  There are several possible ways these series might have happened: if you didn't put them there intentionally, then perhaps inadvertently there was a `Selection ` e.g., "M1:O2" when the chart was created, or perhaps this is an existing chart with existing series, etc... in any case, deleting all series at the beginning will avoid that sort of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this below: safer than relying on the SeriesCollection index.  Also , if you're creating the chart in code then by default it will pick up data from whatever range is currently selected. To be safe you should loop though and delete any existing Series right after creating the chart, before adding the data you want.

```
Dim s 

For m = 4 To 36
    Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
    With s
        .Name = Range("A" & m)
        .XValues = Range("Q" & m)
        .Values = Range("R" & m)
    End With
Next m
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Tim. Looping through and deleting existing series right after I create the chart seems to have fixed my issue. Also the code you posted is much cleaner than mine. Here is what I have now:

Do Until ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop

Dim s

For m = 4 To 36
Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
With s
    .Name = Range("A" & m)
    .XValues = Range("Q" & m)
    .Values = Range("R" & m)
End With
Next m

This code does exactly what I need it to. Thank you again!